# ASP.NET does not seem to need a ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I was working with other Dev team (I'm mostly a winform Dev) and I saw the following:

Our APP is an ASP.NET App. This application(solution) has a webfrom project
and also several VB dlls(for business and data layers).

Recently one ASPX page changed(VB code behind),

And also a dll which this page was using.(VB dll data layer)

So solution was built successfully, without errors.

When they were deploying this change to the webserver they only copied the VB DLL for data layer and the webproject dll. So only 2 dll copied.

My question is why we didn't need to copy ASPX files to webserver?

Comment: Do you know what about the aspx page was changed?

Comment: If you changed the ASPX file (html) they you must update that file as well!

Comment: Are the aspx pages compiled as embedded resources? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856453/how-do-you-put-an-entire-asp-net-website-into-one-dll

Comment: As far as I know, If there were changes to the aspx pages, they need to be deployed together with the other files changed. Maybe the best people to answer the question would be the dev team you were working with. Nothing bad about asking them...

Comment: Yes. One function on ASPX code behind which was calling aonther function in the VB DLL which was writing some data to the database.

Comment: And additionally, from the title of your post... It's unlikely that the site doesn't need that aspx page at all, it's probably just more likely that it wasn't necessary to re-deploy... if you based your use of "change" off of version control, your VC probably flags any change to code as a change to the aspx as well

Comment: I'm wondering, when we comile the solution if changes all go in the web project dll.

Comment: @ Bartdude. I can't ask other DEv team As sadly they are really newbies out of colledge. I'm almost sure even if this works , this is Not the proper way to deploy new changes.

Comment: Compiled sites do not require code-behind files, these are compiled into the DLL's (I think in the bin). This way your source code is not readily available once deployed, which is a good thing

Comment: @musefan. That's clearly the case. But what do you think about our newbie dev team copying them to the production webserver?

Isn't that a security risk?

Comment: Does Anyone see any benefits on copying VB or C# files(code behind) to the server?

Comment: There are no benefits to copying the code behind files, except perhaps because its easier than compiling (although debate-ably). If your server is secure, then having them there shouldn't be an issue. Protecting the source is more a concern if you are releasing the website to a client for testing, who may not have paid for it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Here are results of my re-search so far which I hope the future viewer of this post finds usefull.

If you change a Webpage HTML part you Do need to copy the ASPX page to the server. In this case copying the web project DLL won't reflect HTML changes.

If you only change the code behind and "do not touch" the HTML then you can just copy the DLL to the sever. The Website clearly does not care about code behind VB or C# files.

Note that in my option the above case is highly a bad idea, as now we have a ASPX.VB or ASPX.CS file(s) sitting on the web server which  have  a different code with the dll. Therefore for consistency purposes all of these files should be copied together.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about consistency, the code behind files mean nothing to your server running the website. Just delete them if you wish. However, you will want to keep them all consistent in your source control location - whatever that might be

Comment: @ musefan, Thank you for your comment. You said :"There are no benefits to copying the code behind files, except perhaps because it's easier than compiling ". So you say if we copy code behind files ONLY, it will work?  We don't need to copy the website DLL? I assume even if this works it will be slower since files are not compiled.

Comment: Actually,  I meant copying all the project files, but I don't recommend this, and yes I would expect it to be faster pre-compiled

Answer (score 2):

This might help you to understand the issue.
Aspx pages converts to dlls.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1909746.aspx/1?File+updating+Issue+on+hosting+provider+server+

Comment: I think this is indeed helpful. Based on above link:
"When you are building your project your code got builded as a dll "

So this is my assumption:

Lets say Function A changed in the VB code behind and then solution is built. If you copy this dll to the webserver This function somehow takes over whatever definiton is on the existing  function A on the ASPX page. Since in our case new functionality works.

Comment: Yes. The link contains mine real life problem. After uploading my website to server. There were no effect of any Change I'll do on aspx page or code behind. Even my website works if i delete the page. Then after help of experts I understands the logic. I uploaded by bin directory and every things happen great.